# php strtotime in seconds and minutes

Tags: php, date, strtotime, date-math

i use ths method to find the difference between two timestamp and get the number of seconds between those two times, and i refresh the information with jquery like a counter.

```
$diff = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime('2014-06-25 14:50:03');
$time = intval(date('s', $diff));
echo $time;
```

When the difference is more than 60 seconds, the $time comes back to 0, like a reset.

i would like to display 1 min XX s for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `s` flag for `date()` will never return a value greater than 59 as it only represents the current number of seconds of a given time which can never be more than 59 before rolling over into a new minute.

If you want the total number of seconds you can actually remove your second line of code as the difference between two Unix Timestamps is always in seconds:

```
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime('2014-06-25 14:50:03');
echo $time;
```

If you want to display this as minutes and seconds you can use `DateTime()` which offers better tools for this:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$then = new DateTime('2014-06-25 14:50:03');
$diff = $now->diff($then);
echo $diff->format('%i minutes %s seconds');
```

Answer (score 5):

format the date

```
$diff = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime('2014-06-25 14:50:03');
$time = date('i:s', $diff);
echo $time;
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Pass time like 1 & now 2

```
function diffrencePassTimeAction($DataTime){
    $im = $DataTime - strtotime("now");
  return $im;
}
```

Future time like 2 & now 1

```
function diffrenceFuturTimeAction($DataTime){
    $im = strtotime("now") - $DataTime;
  return $im;
}
```

this function delete (-less)

```
function diffrencePassTimeAction($DataTime){
    if ($DataTime > 0)
        return $DataTime - strtotime("now");
    else
        return strtotime("now"); // OR return 0;
}
```